# Using @Html.ActionLink to pass multiple parameters to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I fully expect the solution to be something simple like a small detail i forgot, but for the life of me i cannot figure out what i am doing wrong

Action Link :

```
 @Html.ActionLink(
        linkText: "Confirm",
        actionName: "AdminVitalBitsCD",
         controllerName: "Configuration",
         routeValues: new
         {
              Title = Model.VitalBit.Title,
              Message = Model.VitalBit.Message,
              IsActive = Model.VitalBit.IsActive,
              IsPriority = Model.VitalBit.IsPriority,
              bitName = Model.VitalBit.BitType.Name,
              Created = Model.VitalBit.Created

         },
              htmlAttributes: null
       )
```

Controller :

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AdminVitalBitsCD(string Title, string Message, bool IsActive, bool IsPriority, string bitName, DateTime Created)
{ 
    return View("~/Views/Configuration/AdminVitalBits.cshtml", viewModel);
}
```

When i click on my link the break point is hit in my controller and no error is thrown. The problem is all of the parameters are either null or their default value (Created = {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}). Am i forgetting something simple?

If anything else is need let me know. Thanks in advance

Comment: what's the link that `ActionLink` is creating?

Comment: copy and pasted from the source it is :<a href="/Configuration/AdminVitalBitsCD?IsActive=False&amp;IsPriority=False&amp;Created=01%2F01%2F0001%2000%3A00%3A00">Confirm</a>

Comment: Try prefixing the property with @ with every property of routesValues. Like @Title e.t.c.

Comment: Nope @ didn't work

Comment: Try adding `[FromUri]` before each input parameters. see if it works.

Comment: Before where exactly? Cause i tried before each ActionLink routeValue and got red squiggles

Comment: You need to put before the each parameter of AdminBitalBitsCD action (controller method). Also, can you please post how the query is formed in HTML when page is rendered?

Comment: I'd like to see how you are populating the ViewModel that's going to the View. Perhaps the values are empty in the Model.VitalBit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much simpler way and open for extension is to send a JSON object back to the controller.  You would need to create an equivalent C# POCO class and use it in the controller but it is pretty simple.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AdminVitalBitsCD(PocoDataClass data)
{ 
    return View("~/Views/Configuration/AdminVitalBits.cshtml", viewModel);
}
```

Add this class to your C# project.

```
public class PocoDataClass 
{
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string Message { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Took a tutorial but i got it working now doing this. Thanks for the help